# xcode 5 connect xib with ViewController class

Tags: uiviewcontroller, xib, xcode5

I'm starting to use Xcode 5.
I have just created a viecController without xib file.
Now I have created a xib file to wire with the ViewController that I created before but i can't do this. What do I have to do to connect xib with ViewController files ? thanks

Answer (score 5):

You need to go on your xib and link the property `view` from the *File's Owner* to your view like the following image :

[image]